# Snapshot comparison for file and folders

Tags: comparison

We are creating a new installer and want a tool to compare the new installation with the old installation. Is there a tool to do a snapshot comparison with a list of differences?

Comment: Is it just one folder? Multiple Folders? Are there changes in the regestry? Regards

Comment: Multiple folders and there are registry changes

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific about what installation do you mean? If the differences are on file-level, you may use simply `diff` command with `-r` option (if you are on NIX system). You may also run for example `rsync -nav --delete` to see the differences. It really depends on your environment.

Comment: This is a windows environment.